# Getting permanent Digg OAuth Credentials

Tags: oauth, digg

I have few doubts and queries regarding Digg OAuth Tokens.
My purpose is to authenticate user once for my application, save the
credentials in database and then access digg API on user's behalf even
when user is offline.

However, there seems to be a problem. The authenticated tokens
initially work fine but expire after sometime resulting in the API
failures with the following error response.
{
    "status": 401,
    "timestamp": 1288905135,
    "message": "OAuth signature is invalid.",
    "code": 5001

}

Please tell me if there is a way I can get permanent tokens (i.e.
which don't expire). Without this, I cannot possibly build an offline
Digg Application. Or, is there a workaround? Please suggest.

-binit

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your/web server time? If this is different than actual it will cause OAuth signature is invalid. I had this issue with about 16mins different in my PC time.